# Changes in flask based python project scripts are completely ignored during execution

Tags: python, flask, connexion

I am working on a python based micro service. Now, changes in any of the scripts used besides the application.py script are completely ignored. Unfortunately I have no idea what changes caused this problem but it broke after moving the Project directory locally and restructuring the file structure.
Has anyone experienced this before and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I found the answer myself. The Problem was that I didn't update the OpenAPI file which links the endpoints to the respective python functions after changing the file-structure of the project!